# Using iPhone as control device (game controller type) in Windows

Tags: iphone, windows, input, driver

Is there a way to use the iPhone as an interface device for a computer without actually having to code a driver? Being the owner of a sub-par game controller and realizing that it would be cheap and a good experience to try to roll my own, I have no idea where to begin on the PC side. I am capable of processing accelerometer and touch events on the iPhone and sending them over a network, but where would I begin on the Windows side? I'd prefer to not get as low level as a driver, but I want to be able to use the accelerometer as an analog input device and buttons on the screen as regular buttons. How should I go about this? If I have to write a driver, what would be a good reference/code sample to start with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write drivers as long as you handle the data being sent by the iPhone on PC. As far as where to begin on PC side, all you need to do is create a small program which listens for data on the socket. You can make that program in any language C, C++, Java etc. I had worked on a similar application as mentioned by you. On PC I used Java with Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: Thanks. Two basic questions—is a socket synonymous with a network port (like 192.168.0.105:2345), or is a different mechanism? Also, how do I turn the data into an input stream, like I might use in a game? I know the game(s) I have in mind support a generic controller…how would I map a UIAcceleration* object to a controller's stick or triggers, or a UITouch* to a button press?

Comment: Well socket does use an IP and a port number to send or receive data. And as far as how to pass data between PC and iPhone that will depend upon the data you have. The application I worked on was fairly simple, it was a wireless mouse. You move your finger on the iPhone the mouse on the PC will move. I sent my data as an array as i had to simply pass the displacement values of iPhone and send it to PC.

Comment: Il give you an example as to how to send data. In the array, there will be flags denoting what event it is and what are the values. If its a button press, the array you will send will have the first element as 1. If its a drag, the second element in the array will be 1 and the rest of the array will contain the values for denoting how much was dragged. If iPhone is tilted towards left, the third element in the array will be 1 and others (first and second element) will be zero. You will have to check the flags and handle the event on PC accordingly.

Comment: For more complex data, arrays might not be feasible but I don't know how to pass a whole structure (like a NSDictionary) of data and handle it on the PC side.

Comment: Thanks. But again, going back to the latter part of my comment—how would I actually handle. the event? How do I map the array (which should suffice) into control events that a game or other application would recognize?

Comment: You have to program both the iPhone and the game such that it is able to recognize the control events. The iPhone will detect what kind of events the user triggered and will set the array you are sending accordingly. The PC side program will have to constantly check the array and recognize what kind of event it is. You have to program as to which array elements will mean what. For example, on a single tap on iPhone set the first array element as 1 and send it to PC. On PC the program will check if the first array element is one. If it is, it means a single tap and handle it accordingly.

Comment: Okay. So there's no way for me to hook it up to an existing, commercial game? I know it can handle a Generic Joystick…is there a way to emulate that?

Comment: Well you can handle the mouse and keyboard events. It is possible to programmatically simulate mouse and keyboard input. Check out this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx . The keyboard inputs will be reflected in your game if your game is running. Basically you can create a whole wireless remote control for your PC.

Comment: Ah, now we're getting somewhere. :) Now is there a way to simulate some form of analog input?

Comment: For example, in a racing game (like NFS, for example), is there a way I can map the accelerometer input into throttle and/or steering?

Comment: I guess you can. On iPhone just track the accelerometer input. If the iPhone is tilted left it can be considered as a left turn. Set the data in the array being sent accordingly. On PC, scan the array and check what input was it. If its a left turn, programmatically call the left arrow button on PC.

Comment: Err…except the arrows wouldn't be analog; they'd be digital. Or maybe I could repeatedly call the arrow in rapid succession, the frequency simulating the analog?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is similar to what Splashtop's Remote does (http://www.splashtop.com/remote/touchpad).  They seem to use a network connection to accomplish this goal.

Also Joypad, same concept (http://getjoypad.com/).

Comment: Remote doesn't handle the constant polling/live updating that a game controller would require. JoyPad looks promising, but each app that I want to use it in would have to use the JoyPad SDK, and that's really not going to happen.

Comment: I wasn't saying you shouldn't create your own solution, was just offering those as an example of how it can be done.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. I'd create my own interface; it would've been nice to see the code behind those solutions.