# Is it possible to register software as a game controller device?

Tags: .net, c, windows, driver

I've seen questions like this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076734/using-iphone-as-control-device-game-controller-type-in-windows) question.  However, in this and many other discussion like it the end result tends to be spamming keyboard events instead of operating, and being recognized as, a game controller.

I'm pretty certain drivers would be necessary to create that additional functionality.  With that in mind, is it possible for a software application to masquerade as an input device like a analog game controller?  I'm very new to developing drivers and this is beyond my scope of knwoledge.

Comment: From a very abstract level, the driver reads *something* and translates it into standard API commands; there's no reason that something couldn't be the output of another program. As for the implementation, *that's* the actual hard part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/vmulti/ it implements a virtual joystick (along with some other devices) and also has a basic client api for synthesizing your own input events

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible in theory. The term I've seen used is "software-only device driver." Since you can make a software-only driver that emulates a storage device (e.g., DAEMON Tools), implementing the DirectInput or XInput interfaces is definitely doable.