# How can i operate my pc using my iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, sockets, networking, remote-access

Basically I need a suggestion about making an iOS application, where I can connect my iPhone to a computer using Wi-Fi.

In my application, I need to control the whole computer, such as software installation, run software, computer shut down, media play, etc.

I want to operate the whole computer using my iPhone.
Now my question is how can I do this?

Comment: [here's a link that may you find interesting](http://cre.ations.net/creation/webvnc---remote-desktop--vnc-on-your-iphone) Good Luck! :)

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076734/using-iphone-as-control-device-game-controller-type-in-windows)

Comment: just implement a VNC/RDP/ARD Client in your app. lol

Comment: Thank you all of you guys.Can you tell me where i will get more help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Teamviewer to get full access to your computer
Can also use

- HippoRemote
- Keymote
- Remote Jr

Comment: thank you for your try but i want to make my own application where i will control my computer using my iphone.

Comment: It would be appreciable, also need some research I think